# How can I use Masonry multiple times per page with the same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry

I need to have multiple Masonry grids per page. I'm generating the code with a wordpress loop, so every div container has the same class name.

Is there a way to call Masonry on all div containers with the same name?

**html**

```
 <!--Masonry 1-->
<div class="print-slider">
    <div class="print-slider-sizer"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
    <div class="print-slider-item"></div>
    <div class="print-slider-item"></div>
    <div class="print-slider-item"></div>
    <div class="print-slider-item"></div>
</div>

<!--Masonry 2-->
<div class="print-slider">
    <div class="print-slider-sizer"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
    <div class="print-slider-item"></div>
    <div class="print-slider-item"></div>
    <div class="print-slider-item"></div>
    <div class="print-slider-item"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var grid = document.querySelector('.print-slider');
var msnry;

imagesLoaded( grid, function() {
  // init Isotope after all images have loaded
  msnry = new Masonry( grid, {
    itemSelector: '.print-slider-item',
    columnWidth: '.print-slider-sizer',
    gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
    percentPosition: true,
  });
});
```

Here is a code pen for the problem:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXBrPb

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `document.querySelector('.print-slider')` you only get the first html element that has the `print-slider` class. That's why only the first masonry is initialized.

Below is your code adjusted a bit in order to catch all `.print-slider` elements and init the masonries respectively. The difference is that I get the elements by class name and then loop through them. I used `body` as the selector for the `imagesLoaded` because I didn't have the whole html structure. I would suggest that you wrap the masonries in one div and use that one for checking whether the images are loaded. Or, even better, do the check for each masonry separately, before doing the initialization inside the foreach.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('print-slider');
var msnry;

imagesLoaded( document.querySelector('body'), function() {
  // init Isotope after all images have loaded
  var n = elements.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    msnry = new Masonry( elements[i], {
      itemSelector: '.print-slider-item',
      columnWidth: '.print-slider-sizer',
      gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
      percentPosition: true,
    });
  }
});
```