# Using Multiple Masonry Grids On Collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, jquery-masonry, masonry

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0Lteo2d/5)

Hey! I've decided to use Masonry, which I find completely awesome.

Although I've ran into the issue where when I use it in a collapsible, it only works on the first collapsible when it's open. I can't seem figure out a way to get it to work when the collapsible is closed and then opened.

I would think it's because when the page loads the images aren't shown/don't exist. I've tried using Juery on click methods for when the collapsible is clicked to load Masonry. That didn't seem to work so I scratched that. I've tried using another on click method to reload Masonry when it's open. That also didn't seem to work correctly.

I am fairly new to JavaScript so I wouldn't be surprised if I had done something wrong. But any help would greatly appreciated. Especially considering I've been banging my head for the last few days on this.

I hope this is enough! Thanks in advance!

HTML :

```
<ul class="collapsible popout">
  <li class="active">
    <div class="collapsible-header">
      <h1 class="bodyFont noMargin">
        Landscapes
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
        <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
        <div class="card deep-purple lighten-4 hoverable" id="Landscapes1" name="Landscapes1">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
            <span class="card-title">Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Description
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Link to album</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card deep-purple lighten-4 hoverable" id="Landscapes2" name="Landscapes2">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
            <span class="card-title">Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Description
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Link To Album</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card deep-purple lighten-4 hoverable" id="Landscapes3" name="Landscapes3">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
            <span class="card-title">Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Description
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Link To Album</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card deep-purple lighten-4 hoverable" id="Landscapes3" name="Landscapes3">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
            <span class="card-title">Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Description
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Link To Album</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card deep-purple lighten-4 hoverable" id="Landscapes3" name="Landscapes3">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
            <span class="card-title">Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Description
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Link To Album</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card deep-purple lighten-4 hoverable" id="Landscapes3" name="Landscapes3">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
            <span class="card-title">Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Description
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Link To Album</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div id="secondCategory" class="collapsible-header">
      <h1 class="bodyFont noMargin">
        Potraits
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="card deep-purple lighten-4" id="Butterflies" name="Butterflies">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
            <span class="card-title">Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Description
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Link To Album</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card deep-purple lighten-4" id="Bees" name="Bees">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
            <span class="card-title">Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Description
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Link To Album</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card deep-purple lighten-4" id="RollyPolies" name="RollyPolies">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
            <span class="card-title">Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Description
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Link To Album</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card deep-purple lighten-4" id="Ants" name="Ants">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x350">
            <span class="card-title">Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>
              Description
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">Link To Album</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
  margin: 0%;
}

.card,
.grid-sizer {
  width: 31.3%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.gutter-sizer {
  width: 2%;
}
```

JS:

```
  $(".collapsible").collapsible();
  var $grid = $(".grid");
  $grid.masonry({
    itemSelector: ".card",
    columnWidth: ".grid-sizer",
    gutter: ".gutter-sizer",
    percentposition: true,
    horizontalOrder: true
  });

  $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
    $grid.masonry("layout");
  });
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this link was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765659/how-can-i-use-masonry-multiple-times-per-page-with-the-same-class-name
Although my problem lies in that it only loads the opened collapsible and not the second that's closed and then opened, if that makes some sense

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f0Lteo2d/24/

I've add a second class to the second grid and to the second cards using a on click method to initialize masonry for the second and that seems to work, but it's not an ideal solution.... For now it works though